# Authorize with Controllers with AD Groups using OIDC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

we have a web application which uses OIDC for single sign on to authenticate with
Azure AD. The single sign on works great, Users are able to sign in with their AD accounts. The token it returns also contains AD groups.
I would like to authorize my MVC controllers to only allow certain groups to use certain controllers.

How do I implement this? I can see the groups are being sent back in the token represented as GUIDs.
I have tried setting the role claims via  `RoleClaimType = "roles",` but this doesn't work.

here is my code.

```
  public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        FATContext db = new FATContext();

        

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    // Set claimsPrincipal's roles to the roles claim
                    RoleClaimType = "roles",
                },
               
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {

                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                       
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Home", null, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        
                        var code = context.Code;
                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                        return authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                           code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);
                    }
                }
            });
      


    }
```

So for example, how can I get this to work with my controller such as

```
 [AuthorizeUser(Roles = "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

or to check is a user is in a certain role i.e  `User.IsInRole("example ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure AD we can define application roles and assign the roles to the groups.
Now the users of this group will have a claim with the roles defined(example as shown below). Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) for the detailed documentation on how to create/manage roles for an application in Azure AD.

```
{
  "roles": ["admin"]
}
```

If you are just trying to use groups-based authorization you can use *RoleClaimType = "groups"* and the below example codes in controller or in the action methods. For more details you have similar information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/azure-app-service-authentication-app-roles)

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class TestAdminAccessController : ApiController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                // Your logic
            }
            else
            {
                // is NOT an admin. No permissions
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // is NOT Authenticated;    
        }
    }
}
```